# Make ComboBox 2 not select a same value with ComboBox 1

Tags: c#, date, ms-access, combobox

i have a question. This question came out in my mind, but i don't know how to do it.
I got a 2 ComboBoxes, each ComboBox store a `Date`, and when user run the program and user select a `Date` of `29/8/2013` in ComboBox 1, automatically ComboBox 2 select next day `30/8/2013` from the `Date` selected in ComboBox 1, and / or previous date in ComboBox 2 will not be available to click or blocked (Because ComboBox 1 as starting date is select `Date` of `29/8/2013`, so the previous date of `29/8/2013` will not be available to click or blocked)

How do i do that?

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

in the screenshot above, i select date `9/30/2013` from ComboBox 1 as Start Date. And the ComboBox 2 should automatically select next day of `9/30/2013`, so it suppose to select `10/01/2013` and the previous date from `9/30/2013` will be blocked or unable to click by user in the ComboBox 2 as End Date.

I appreciate your answer.
Thank you very much!

Here is the code:

```
    public partial class Trans : Form
    {
        private List<DateTime> _startDate = new List<DateTime>();
        private List<DateTime> _endDate = new List<DateTime>();

        public Trans()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Trans(Choices _choice)
            : this()
        {
            this._choice = _choice;
        }

        private void Trans_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < DateTime.Today.AddYears(1).Subtract(DateTime.Today).TotalDays + 1; i++)
            {
                _startDate.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(i));
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < DateTime.Today.AddYears(1).Subtract(DateTime.Today).TotalDays + 1; i++)
            {
                _endDate.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(i));
            }

            StartDateCollection(sender, e);
            EndDateCollection(sender, e);
        }

        private void StartDateCollection(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string query = "SELECT [Dates] FROM [TransRecord]";

                conn.Open();

                using (OleDbDataAdapter _adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
                {
                    comboBox1.DataSource = _startDate;
                    comboBox1.FormatString = "M/dd/yyyy";
                    comboBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
                }
            }
        }

        private void EndDateCollection(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
            {
                string query = "SELECT [Dates] FROM [TransRecord]";

                conn.Open();

                using (OleDbDataAdapter _adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, conn))
                {
                    comboBox2.DataSource = _endDate;
                    comboBox2.FormatString = "M/dd/yyyy";
                    comboBox2.FormattingEnabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you populate combobox1 ?

Comment: +1 for Good logical question

Comment: hai, i will post the code in the question. Sorry for not posting it earlier

Answer (score 0):

Populate `EndDateCollection` in the Change event of `StartDateCollection`

This will fill only allowed values into the `EndDateCollection` combo box

```
private void StartDateCollection_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Clear the items in EndDateCollection

    // Fill EndDateCollection - Start at (StartDateCollection's DateTime).AddDays(1)
}
```

Based on your edit, I would suggest getting the max end date form the database, then fill dates up to that date. Also add a check to make sure you are not already at the max date in `EndDateCollection`

Answer (score 0):

get first combobox value

example : 30/9/2013

Add one day with the 1st combobox value

```
DateTime dt=Convert.ToDateTime("30/9/2013").AddDay(1);
```

Now the `dt` value is 1/10/2013

Set the `combobox selected.item =1/10/2013`

It's just like a key only , You need to some date time format . Do it yourself .

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the properly way to do it, perhaps, if you put logic on Combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sebder, EventArgs e){} that takes the selected date string you can make able to be clicked in the second combobox just the dates that are higher than it.

Hope it gives you a way to follow

bye